# AngularJs - modal window w/ajax loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I'm trying to enable a modal window pop up for elements on an application that displays more information (including things like comments etc) using ui.bootstrap (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal). The element is being loaded as a directive on the page, and I think i'm running into an issue with nested scopes, however it appears as though the modal window is triggering, but nothing is appearing (the screen fades).

My directive looks like this:

```
    .directive('artifactCause', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                thing: '=thing'
            },
            templateUrl: 'views/directives/artifact-cause.html',
            controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $modal) {
                console.log('clicked');
                $scope.open = function() {

                    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                        backdrop: true,
                        keyboard: true,
                        controller: 'artifactModalCtrl',
                        templateUrl: 'views/directives/modal-artifact.html',
                        scope: $scope,
                        resolve: {
                            thing: function () {
                                return $scope.thing.cause_id;
                            }
                        }
                    });

                };
            }
        };
    });
```

and the artifactModealCtrl controller looks like this:

```
.controller('artifactModalCtrl', function($scope, $http, loggedStatus, thing) {
        var token = loggedStatus.token();
        $scope.close = function(result) {
            dialog.close(result);
        };

        $http.get( REQUEST_URL + '/Artifact/ArtifactDetail?token=' + token + '&artifact_id=' + thing ).
            success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.thing = data.response;
                return data.response;
            }).
            error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error');
                console.log(data);
            });
    })
```

I know that the data i'm receiving from my ajax call is successful as I can log it to the console. Any insight or pointers in the right direction would be muchly appreciated.

Comment: Did you include the css for bootstrap?

Comment: @lucuma yes, i've got it running on a different page without any controllers attached to it. You think it's a styling issue? I thought it was weird that I could see the elements appear on my browser, but not display on the page, however I wasn't sure if it could be a JS problem..

Comment: I had a similar issue and it was because of styling. Check in inspector if the modal is appended to your document body

Comment: @lort There are 2 modal div's added to the document body, but there is not a class of "modal" applied to the body tag, is this what you mean? - When the open function is called, the site greys out (as it should), just no modal window appears. The modal HTML seems to be missing the guts unfortunately :(

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error but it seems to work just fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/fLWAarDeP3ij1NrCqZiZ

Comment: @lort It appears as though the .modal is not display:block.

Comment: @lort can you create an answer for the question so that I can +1 your answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue of the HTML template not being found. The modal is launching and fading the screen, but the template isnt found so nothing is showing on the screen.
I personally have not had success in referencing a template's file location in the `templateUrl` property, so instead what I do is include the html template in a masterpage or whatever page will be firing off the modal, like so:

```
<div ng-include src="'../views/directives/modal-artifact.html'">
```

Make sure the path to your template is accurate, you should be able to confirm this by viewing the contents of the file via firebug (or similar browser dev tool) on page load.

Next, assuming the `id` attribute of your template tag is `"modal-artifact.html"` (`<script type="text/ng-template" id="modal-artifact.html">`), set your templateUrl like this:

```
templateUrl: 'modal-artifact.html' //this must match the id of your template
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I can see that the template is loading properly through the network tab. Good thought though.